# How to call an API with an array of strings as the parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have an endpoint like below:

```cs
[HttpPost("GetSchoolsDetails")]
public ActionResult<SchoolModel> GetSchoolsDetails(string[] SchoolsUuid)
{
    //some code
}
```

I'm trying to call this endpoint in some other place like below

```cs
var requestUrl = $"http://localhost:6200/api/Schools/GetSchoolsDetails";
var stringContent = new StringContent(SchoolsUuid.ToString());
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", _infrastructureAuthKey);
    response = client.PostAsync(requestUrl, stringContent);
    response.Wait();

}
```

But here I'm getting an "Unsupported Media Type" error.

Please let me know a better way to call the API by passing an array as a parameter.

Comment: Hint: what `Content-Type` header is `StringContent` setting for your http call, and what Content Type does your API expect?

Comment: Pretty sure that your API is expecting JSON. `var content = JsonSerializer.Serialize(SchoolsUuid)` and POST that.

Comment: well, that spoils the hint

Comment: GetSchoolsDetails - endpoint expects string array..

Comment: @VasanthR that reply tells me that you don't understand what HTTP Content Types are. Read over https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Serialize the `SchoolsUuid` array.
2. Specify the Content-Type as "application/json".

```cs
using System.Text;

var stringContent = new StringContent(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(SchoolsUuid)
    , Encoding.UTF8
    , "application/json");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use PostAsJsonAsync extension and simply send the array expected by the server.

```cs
var requestContent = new [] { SchoolsUuid.ToString() };
response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUrl, requestContent);
```